# How to add schema to another schema array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have address schema and customer schema. I have a field address array inside my customer schema. I will be sending an adress model as my req body and customer id as req param. How can I save that adress to adresses array which is declared inside customer schema?

**This is my Customer Schema**

```
const customerSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  phone_number: String,
  password: String,
  type:{type:String,enum:['admin','user']},
  adresses:['Adress'],
  orders:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order'}]
});
```

**This is my Adress Schema**

```
const addressSchema= mongoose.Schema({
    _id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    postalCode:Number,
    city:String,
    district:String,
    neighborhood:String,
    streetNumber:String,
    no:Number,
    buildingName:String,
    apartmentNumber:Number,
    floor:Number,
    coordinates:{
        latitude:Number,
        longitude:Number
    },
    addressName:String,
    customerId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Customer'}


});
```

I could not figure out how am ı going to do this. I am finding the customer which I will going to push my address to like this.

**This is how I get the specific customer**

```
Customer.find({_id:req.params.customerId},(err,data)=>{
    if(err) return next(err);
    else{
      //What I am going to do here?
    }
});
```

First what type should I put inside the addresses array which is inside Customer Schema?

Second after finding the customer which I am going to add address to, what should I do? Mongoose 5.4.11 documentation was not enough for me. This link seemed what I needed but I did not figure out how to accomplish this problem.

> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, so basically what You look for is: association. You need to establish a connection between User and Customer model.

We will say that Address belongs to the User and User reference Address object by for example id.

Consider an example:

```
const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Now let's try to assign an author to particular created story:

```
const author = new Person({
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  name: 'Ian Fleming',
  age: 50
});

author.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  const story1 = new Story({
    title: 'Casino Royale',
    author: author._id    // assign the _id from the person
  });

  story1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // thats it!
  });
});
```

When you define relation between Story and Person, it is easy to manipulate references between them.

In your case you should define a reference in models and then you are able to manipulate the fields:

```
Customer.findOne({_id:req.params.customerId}, function(error, customer) {
  if (error) {
    return handleError(error);
  }
  customer.address = newAddress; // set customer's address to the desired address
  // console.log(customer.address.city);
});
```

Check [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually I accomplished the association solution before. Your answer works for a user story like, after user picks the products for ordering before order s/he can chose between the address s/he added. Which I just should take the customer id, than I have to return every adress which associates with that id. Cool. But at the same time I will assoc orders to customers as well. Than when admin wants to check every user with their orders and their adresses, database has to cehck on three collections.

Comment: Ok and where is the problem?

Comment: I want to take all the pre-orders and all adresses of user, in the first place. I can do this with your solution as well with just changing my queries etc. So which is more efficient. Assoc strategy or just adding thoose adresses and orders inside customer schema.(I mean inside their related array fields)

Comment: @KarIR I have just added my last question. Can you share your idea just on this one?